# Social (Classmate like) database schema appreciation

Tags: database-design

This is a database schema I propose for a networking website like the Classmates.com web site.

Do you think the database has all the tables needed for such a project? What would you rather do?

The database has 3 parts:

- the payment part is surrounded by the black color box
- the social part by the blue color box
- the classmates part by the red color box

Any advice or critics is welcome. thanks.

I have been inspired by database models presented on the [databaseanswers.org](http://www.databaseanswers.org/) web site.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just personal preferences, but to me your schema lacks the ability to keep track of name changes due to marriage, etc, timestamps of the name changes, password lockout counts, last logon times, physical addresses for schools, display names in the Contacts table, video name, profile photo titles/descriptions, blah blah blah.

Comment: Thanks Beeks for comments. About  the ability to keep track of name changes (timestamps of the name changes, password lockout counts, last logon times) do I have to add those new fields into the Users table?

Comment: i would break out the users table into a Users table and UserProperties table, joined by the PK Users_ID. The Users table would store information about the user that we don't need to keep a historical record of, like:
Users_ID
User_Create_Time
Last_Logon_Date
Password_Hash
Failed_Logon_Attempts
User_DOB
etc..

Then on the UserProperties table
Users_ID
Property_ID
EffectiveStartDate
Property_Type
Property_Value

Then you can join the User to the property to the date and the time, to find the state of a user's information at any point in time.

Answer (score 1):

### 1.   `payment` (black box)

**1.1)  No currency information?**
In the `Payments` table, although you store an `amount` and `date`, you store no currency.  Perhaps you plan on only charging in one currency, but I feel that method will only last so long if this is intended to scale.

**1.2)  What is this second `payments` table?**
What is the second `payments` table for?  The one below and slightly left of the *actual* `payments` table?
It seems to have only an `id` column, which is the only column in this diagram to specify a data type!?  I'm guessing this is some diagram artefact.

**1.3)  You'll need more than just the `name` to take payments!**
The `payment_methods` table currently doesn't store the **type** (*i.e.* credit card, paypal, BitCoin, whatever) of the method.  There also seems to be no linked table of payment_types for this either.

You will need to store stuff like credit card numbers, etc *somewhere*  (hopefully not in this database!).  You will need some sort of *linking* information for those stored payment methods to be kept in the `payment_methods` table.

---

### 2.   `social` (blue box)

**2.1)  Who exactly is `me`?**
I'm assuming the `Me` table is some sort of *façade* or *profile* type of table.  Perhaps allowing a given `User` to shield themselves from the embarrassment of letting their collage/university friends see the `Music` they were into in high school? :P

I do not believe it makes sense to **double** store the first, middle and last names of the user.  It would be **much** better to go with a solution like that which [@beeks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/26443/beeks) [suggested in the comments above](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125409/social-classmate-like-database-schema-appreciation#comments-125409).

**2.2)  `My_Profile_Details`... *field*?**
I cannot figure out *why* this is a **single** field.  I assume it's some sort of `memo` type, for storing a lot of text (*i.e.* a CV of sorts).  I think this needs **MUCH** more decomposition.  At a minimum, into *Sections* of some sort.

There also seems to be nothing in a `Proflie` that allows a user to select what Schools/Collages/Universities/Enterprises they studied/worked at, etc?

---

### 3.   `classmates` (red box)

**3.1)  Internationalisation?**
This part of your design is missing information regarding *country*. Even if you're only looking for schools/colleges in a particular county, employers (which is what I assume `Enterprise` is for) may be in **any** country.

Also, If a *classmate* **starts** their own enterprise, do they have the **same** *relationship* to that enterprise as someone who works for it?

**3.2)  Institution Names**
You have assumed Universities (and I suppose high schools, primary schools and collages too) **have only one name**, and *that name is in English* (or whatever language you're intending to store).
It is quite common for universities to have different names in different languages.  Institution names can also change over time (renamed, etc).

**3.3) Institution Decomposition**
Not all Universities divide themselves into Faculties, some are simply a collection of `Schools` (think Oxford, etc).  These can also change name over time.  Also, both faculties (schools), universities (and probably collages, primary and secondary schools too) can **merge** (*i.e.* get taken over/bought out) over time.

**3.4) Institution Location Multiplicity**
Your design seems to assume a University can only be in *one* `town`.  Many Universities have different **campuses** in *different* towns.  Some even have campuses across international borders.